# Android Studio - cannot resolve method and simbol

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on a simple app but today, just after I clicked on "clean project" my apps can't be run anymore due some errors about drawable resources.

I have this simple activity:

```
package com.elisafedeli.consiglipergenitori.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class About extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    //Variabili
    ImageButton fb = null;
    ImageButton twitter = null;
    ImageButton linkedin = null;
    ImageButton sito = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Mostro la grafica
        setContentView(android.R.layout.about);

        //Recupero tutti i pulsanti
        fb = (ImageButton)findViewById(android.R.id.logoFB);
        twitter = (ImageButton)findViewById(android.R.id.logoTwitter);
        linkedin = (ImageButton)findViewById(android.R.id.logoLindedIn);
        sito = (ImageButton)findViewById(android.R.id.logoSito);

        //Aggiungo il click listener
        fb.setOnClickListener(this);
        twitter.setOnClickListener(this);
        linkedin.setOnClickListener(this);
        sito.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Ad ogni listener aggiungo un valore così posso eseguire azioni diverse
        fb.setTag(0);
        twitter.setTag(1);
        linkedin.setTag(2);
        sito.setTag(3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Recupero il valore del bottone
        Integer valore_bottone = (Integer) v.getTag();
        Intent ritorno;

        switch (valore_bottone){
            case 0:{
                ritorno = getOpenFacebookIntent(getApplicationContext());
                startActivity(ritorno);
                break;
            }
            case 1:{
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    //Se l'app di FB è installata apro la pagina
    //Altrimenti il browser
    public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context) {

        try {
            context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
            return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/510231222394702"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/pages/Bambini-al-nido/510231222394702"));
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not able to compile it, I have errors on:

```
setContentView(android.R.layout.about);
```

and

```
fb = (ImageButton)findViewById(android.R.id.logoFB);
        twitter = (ImageButton)findViewById(android.R.id.logoTwitter);
        linkedin = (ImageButton)findViewById(android.R.id.logoLindedIn);
        sito = (ImageButton)findViewById(android.R.id.logoSito);
```

and AndroidStudio report:

```
Gradle invocation completed successfully with 6 error(s) in 10 sec
```

and

[image]

But, as you can see the resources are in the drawable folders (and it worked before my clean):

[image]

and are correctly set in the xml layout:

[image]

How can I solve?

Comment: Cleaning the project at times is not able to associate projects R.java with the resources.

A simple build may do the trick. Try restarting eclipse again and see if it works.

Comment: No, same error. I have solved with the @eightx2's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `android.R` with `R` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

R import missing,

add your R file

```
import com.elisafedeli.consiglipergenitori.app.R;
```